# jquery issues image dissapears sometimes on window scroll function

Tags: jquery, function, scrollto, preloader

I am experiencing a weird problem with jquery (mostly in firefox and IE9). Here is the situation. I have a horizontal scrolling website that depending on your scroll position and content section an image on the top right corner changes so that the user knows which section he is on. The scroll positions for the image change are calculated through jquery depending on the user window width. I have an easing on the menus so its animated going from section to section and also my images for the top right corner are preloaded at the beginning and also hard coded(http://karpouzaki.com/easing/img/image.png) in my css and also on the image replacement which happens with jquery function.
This is what I have in my head section:

```
<link media="screen" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link media="screen" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link media="screen" type="text/css" href="fonts.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/media-queries.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/hscroll.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/function.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="yoxview/yoxview-init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$.each(["http://karpouzaki.com/easing/img/naboutus.png","http://karpouzaki.com/easing/img/nwhatwedo.png","http://karpouzaki.com/easing/img/ntheory.png","http://karpouzaki.com/easing/img/nportfolio.png","http://karpouzaki.com/easing/img/nclients.png","http://karpouzaki.com/easing/img/ncontacts.png"],function(i,url){
var img = new Image();
img.src = url;
});   
$(window).load(function(){
sitewidths();
    scpos();
multibgpos();
$(window).resize(function() {
    sitewidths();
    scpos();
multibgpos();
})
.resize();//trigger the resize event on page load
});
</script>
```

These are my functions where the widths of page are calculated along with the scroll positions for the image replacement and also for the animation between content sections

```
$(function() {
    $('div.navigation a , div.footleft a' ).bind('click',function(event){
        var $anchor = $(this);

        /*if you want to use one of the easing effects:
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
        }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');
        */ 
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
        }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
var scpos = function(){
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var wwidth = $(window).width();
    var spos1 = wwidth - 355;
    var spos2 = spos1+wwidth;
    var spos3 = spos2 + wwidth;
    var spos4 = spos3 + wwidth + $('.rightporto').width();
    var spos5 = spos4 + wwidth + $('.leftclients').width();
    if(($(window).scrollLeft() >= 0)&& ($(window).scrollLeft() < spos1)){
                $(".step").css('background','url(http://karpouzaki.com/easing/img/naboutus.png) 94% 5% no-repeat fixed');
              } else if(($(window).scrollLeft() >= spos1)&& ($(window).scrollLeft() < spos2)){
                  $(".step").css('background','url(http://karpouzaki.com/easing/img/nwhatwedo.png) 94% 5% no-repeat fixed');
              } else if(($(window).scrollLeft() >= spos2 )&& ($(window).scrollLeft() < spos3)){
                  $(".step").css('background','url(http://karpouzaki.com/easing/img/ntheory.png) 94% 5% no-repeat fixed');
              } else if(($(window).scrollLeft() >= spos3)&& ($(window).scrollLeft() < spos4)){
                  $(".step").css('background','url(http://karpouzaki.com/easing/img/nportfolio.png) 94% 5% no-repeat fixed');
              } else if(($(window).scrollLeft() >= spos4)&& ($(window).scrollLeft() < spos5)){
                  $(".step").css('background','url(http://karpouzaki.com/easing/img/nclients.png) 94% 5% no-repeat fixed');
              }else {
                  $(".step").css('background','url(http://karpouzaki.com/easing/img/ncontacts.png) 94% 5% no-repeat fixed');
              } 
        });
};
var sitewidths = function(){
$(function(){
    var dwidth = $(window).width();
    var dportowidth = dwidth + $('.rightporto').width();
    var dclientwidth = dwidth + $('.rightclients').width();
    var cw = $(".rightclients").width();
    var bdwidth = (dwidth * 4) + dportowidth + dclientwidth;
    var mrportclients = Number(($(window).width() * 0.05)); 
        $('body').css("width" , bdwidth);
        $(".multiplebgs .habout").css("width",dwidth);
        $(".multiplebgs .hwhatwedo").css("width",dwidth);
        $(".multiplebgs .htheory").css("width",dwidth);
        $(".multiplebgs .hportfolio").css("width", dportowidth);
        $(".multiplebgs .hclients").css("width", dclientwidth);
        $(".multiplebgs .hcontacts").css("width",dwidth);
        $(".portofolio").css("margin-right" , mrportclients); 
        $('#content4 .cbox').css('margin-right' , mrportclients);
        $(".clients").css("margin-right" , mrportclients);
        $('#content5 .cbox').css('margin-right' , mrportclients);
    });
};
var multibgpos = function(){
$(function(){
    var pwwidth = $(window).width();
        var pwheight =  $(window).height();
    var bg1posx = $('.leftporto').outerWidth() - $('.portofolio').width();
    var hawd = ($(window).width() * 0.05);
    var wasd =  $('.yoxview').css('margin-top').replace('px', '');
    var bg1posy = pwheight - $('.footer').height();
    var bg2posx = $('.leftporto').outerWidth() - Number(($(window).width()) * 0.05);

    var bg2posy =  Number(hawd) + Number(wasd);     
$('#content4').css('background-position', bg1posx+'px '+'bottom, '+bg2posx+'px '+bg2posy+'px ');
    });
};
```

The site is on:

http://karpouzaki.com/easing/

I have changed the window.load to document.ready still the same. I thought it was my animation on the navigation links still nothing. I have a mousescroll on horizontal scrolling but I am not using the mouse scroll when the problem happens so I ruled that out. It just seems to me that either the users session expires and it forces the bg images to be reloaded again thats why the dissapear or there something wrong with my functions.

Anybody got any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: The first `$.each`, is that called from within a jQuery `$(document).ready(function() { }` ? - Could you try it like that ?

Comment: ok i have given it a go to see what happens although I already did have it in a document.reday and tested it. What I did now is just put the preloader or $.each inside the document.ready and left the rest outside to see if it works.Before when I used the document ready I put everything inside it so lets see if it works

Comment: When you dynamically add the images using runtime, the selectors that are already defined under $(document).ready may not work. Wrap all the functions inside a single named function and call the function after loading the images.

Answer (score 0):

Changed my function and added it directly to the header instead of an external function sheet and the problem fixed itself.
Thanks for the help